# Why do the regex patterns '\d+[^-]' behave unexpectedly?

Tags: sql, regex, regex-negation

I am attempting to extract strings that start with any sequence of digits and are followed by any character except '-'

For example,
For the string '123-foo', I expect the result to be 'false'.
For the string '130 boo', I expect the result to be 'true'.
I used the regular expression '\d+[^-]' for this purpose, but it unexpectedly returned both values. However, when I used the regex '\d+[-]', it returned only '123-foo'.

Comment: If you expect to match at whitespace or end of string, use `(\s|$)` explicitly (`\d+(\s|$)` or even `(\s|^)\d+(\s|$)`).

Comment: Use `^\d+[^\d-]`. Your regex  matches one or two digits for `\d+` and a digit for `[^-]` so both results are positive. Unrelated but personally I prefer `^[0-9]+[^0-9-]`, less cryptic. Don't forget the `^` start anchor.

Comment: Add a dbms tag the next time you ask a SQL question here. There are differences between the products.